# Forming a JSON post request with Boost asio

Tags: http-headers, boost-asio

I don't usually get this low level, so I think I'm just missing something obvious with the header.

Here's the code:

```
request_stream << "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                  "Host: localhost:5000 \r\n"
                  "Accept: */*\r\n"
                  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n";
request_stream << "Content-Length: " << json.length() << "\r\n\r\n";
request_stream << json;
```

The resulting string is

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000 
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 34

{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}
```

I then send the request_stream string to the server. I can connect to the server, but it says "bad request". I'm guessing there's something wrong with the above string. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the request was fine. The issue was the simple Flask server I set up. I was calling

```
print(request.get_json())
```

when I should've have been calling

```
print(request.form.get('data'))
```